# Change needed role for command discord.py

Tags: python, command, discord.py

this is not the full code but it's only what I need to explain, if a person wants to use this command he needs the role 'Admin' but let's say I want to change 'Admin' to 'Mod' with another command, how can I do that without changing it from the code itself?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_role("Admin")
```

Comment: you can't with a decorator

Comment: Maybe this works if you set "Admin" as a variable and later edit that with some code? But I am not sure if this will work

Comment: no you can't I already tried, you need to restart the bot so it recognizes the variable @FlexGames

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the decorator you should create your own one

```py
role_name = "Admin"

def has_role(item=None):
    def predicate(ctx):
        nonlocal item # So we can edit it's value
        if item is None or item != role_name: # If either the `item` is `None` or it's not the same as the global `role_name` variable, update it
            item = role_name 

        if not isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.abc.GuildChannel):
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage()

        if isinstance(item, int):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id=item)
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, name=item)
        if role is None:
            raise commands.MissingRole(item)
        return True

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

This is mostly copied from the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1551-L1590) just with a few tweaks

To edit the role necessary to run the command you could simply do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def change(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    global role_name
    role_name = role.name
    await ctx.send(f"Updated to {role.name}")


@bot.command()
@has_role()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Whatever")
```

Comment: why do we need to create the predicate? can't we just return `has_role(item)`?

Comment: Not really, the outmost function will only be called once (when decorating the command), we need to “update” the item variable every time the command runs, it’s kind of the basics of decorators